# How can I get values from a view in Django every time I access the home page

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following view created in Django:

```
@login_required
def retrieve_from_db(request):
  some_ids = get_some_data()
  context = {'some_ids': some_ids}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blabla'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.another_view, name='index'),
   path('', views.retrieve_from_db, name='index'),
   ...
   ...
   ...
]
```

And this is part of my `index.html`

```
<div>
  <select name="myIdList" id="myIdList">
  {% for some_id in some_ids %}
      <option value="{{ some_id }}">{{ some_id }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

I would like to know how can I get the results from the function `retrieve_from_db()`. What I want is that every time I access the home page, by default the selects are populated with the result of the view.

All I have found so far on StackOverflow have been answers using forms in which the user somehow has to perform some action to trigger the POST, is there any way to do all of this without the user having to press any buttons or perform an action? simply every time the page loads, get the results of the `retrieve_from_db()` function defined in the view.

Comment: if the results are user data who is requesting the view just filter by request.user, or maybe you want data from values defined in the URL?

Comment: What is the issue with the current setup? make sure that ```some_ids``` is not empty..

Comment: Why do `another_view` and `retrieve_from_db` have the same url pattern? Since the pattern is same only the **first** one i.e. `another_view` is ever used. If you want those variables `some_ids` in `another_view` you should be writing that code in `another_view`...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for the answer, I am not very familiar with django and what I wanted was to have the data loaded on the home page, without having to use another url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "GET" method **which is not safe for passing sensitive data!**
GET should send data while rendering page.

Your views.py function to retrieve data would look like this:

```
 @login_required
  def retrieve_from_db(request, some_id):
  if request.method == "GET":
      some_ids = request.GET.get('some_id')
      context = {'some_ids': some_ids}
      return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
  <div>
  <form action="/retrieve_from_db/{{some_id}}" method="GET">
  <select name="myIdList" id="myIdList">
  {% for some_id in some_ids %}
      <option value="{{ some_id }}">{{ some_id }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Interesting part here is, how it will pass many 'some_id' objects as you generate them from for loop.

This solution maybe is not one of the most elegant ones, but should pass data without user  interference.